# Single optional parameter on asp.net core routing in Controller

Tags: asp.net-core, controller, routes, http-get

I want to know how to set url path with single optional parameter with prefix routing path.
Because when I try to do [HttpGet("id:int?}"], then I try to access
"[myserver]/prefix"
it's not working.

I do this for
[myserver]/prefix
[myserver]/prefix/1

This is route setting
Prefix
    [Route("manage/test")]
function
    [HttpGet("{id:int?}")

I know it's working with additional routing setting
-> [HttpGet("")]
Or
Setting prefix route
   [Route("manage")]
function route
   [HttpGet("test/{id:int?}"]

But I wanna know why the first parameter is the only one word of routing and it's not working.

```
[Route("manage/test")]
public class ManageController : BaseController //(inherited from Controller)
{
    //[HttpGet("")]
    [HttpGet("{id:int?}"]
    public IActionResult Index(int? id = null)
    {
    }
}
```

For this "[myserver]/prefix"

The view '/Views/manage/test/.cshtml' was not found. The following locations were searched: /Views/manage/test/.cshtml

But for "[myserver]/prefix/1"

The view '/Views/manage/test/.cshtml' was not found. The following locations were searched: /Views/manage/test/Index.cshtml

```
[Route("manage")]
public class ManageController
{
    [HttpGet("{id:int?}"]
    public IActionResult Index(int? id = null)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the content in `Index`? For the View not found error, it is related with the return in `Index` instead of routing. Share us detail steps to reproduce your issue.

Comment: thx to answer, that is just for example. so in real code with "return view()"

Comment: my point, when i just wrote
[HttpGet("{id:int?"}")]
isn't work url manage/test

Comment: Is there any demo to reproduce your issue?

Comment: For that I need to add [HttpGet("")]. But as u know, {id?} means id is optional parameter. But it's not working as only single parameter without any pre-additional path.

Comment: hope that is enough.

Comment: i just delete value's name

Comment: Can you check your code carefully? Are you sure your current code will be complie? What is `BaseController` for first part? For second code part, it even not inherited from `ControllerBase`.

Comment: BaseContoller is inherited from ControllerBase. So you mean {id:int?} is ok to use. right!? I just want to know about that. coz when i search about that one, everyone just using like [HttpGet("manage/{id}")] I didn't see any of  only optional parameter without any path. That is my question.

Comment: I said It's working with add one more line with [HttpGet("")], then ok to access [myserver]/manage. But i wanna know it should work and it's enough only  [HttpGet("{id:int?"}")] for [myserver]/manage & [myserver]/manage/1  Thank you so much @TaoZhou

Answer (score 1):

> {id:int?} is ok to use. right!?

It's ok to use `[HttpGet("{test:int?}")]`.

Here is a demo code:

```
[Route("manage")]
public class ManageController: Controller
{
    [HttpGet("{id:int?}")]
    public IActionResult Index(int? id = null)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

For request `https://localhost:5001/manage`, it will be routed to `Index` with id as null

For request `https://localhost:5001/manage/123`, it will be routed to `Index` with id as 123.

Comment: thank you so much. as you said, i try to do controller then it works. so i said to my coworker who made basecontroller. but actually he is already checking that. thank you once again.